# Android app, SMS/text to speech (has leaked serviceConnection)

Tags: android, sms, text-to-speech, serviceconnection

I have this application listens for incoming messages and reads them aloud. The problem is I get the following error when I exit

> 12-21 15:45:29.949: E/ActivityThread(566): Activity mo.rach.collaboration.speaker has leaked ServiceConnection
>   android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection@41397858 that was
>   originally bound here

I basically would like it to run in the background so that if the app is closed that messages are still read aloud. I really need to figure this out before I go back to uni on the 9th as this is the hand-in date for the project.

**smsReceiver.java**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class smsreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int n; 
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
                for (n = 0; n<messages.length; n++) 
                {
                smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
                }
                // show first message
                String sms1 = smsMessage[0].getMessageBody();
                String from = smsMessage[0].getOriginatingAddress();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,"SMS Received from "+from+":" + sms1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                speaker.speakSMS(sms1);             
            }

    }
```

**speaker.java**

```
import android.speech.tts.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class speaker extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static TextToSpeech myTts;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        myTts = new TextToSpeech(this, ttsInitListener);

    }
    private TextToSpeech.OnInitListener ttsInitListener = new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        public void onInit(int version) {
          //myTts.speak(""+o, 0, null);
        }
      };

   public static void speakSMS(String sms)
   {
       myTts.speak(sms, 0, null);
       myTts.synthesizeToFile(sms,null, "/sdcard/myappsounds/mysms.wav");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your speaker class try to add:

```
void onDestroy() {
    if(dTTS != null) {
       dTTS.stop();
       dTTS.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO). Please, Try to be a little bit more verbose when you answer. Try to explain what you are doing.